# Can you mount a Persistent Volume Claim on a mounted volume?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Is it possible to mount a Persistent Volume Claim on the path of a volume mount. Here is an example of a deployment with said configuration:

```
      volumes:
        - name: tmp
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-claim-name

          volumeMounts:
            - name: tmp
              mountPath: /tmp
            - name: pvc
              mountPath: /tmp/pvc
```

Would the PVC be deleted when the mounted `tmp` volume is deleted with the container?

Will the PVC remain after being deployed to within a mounted volume, which will be deleted with the container?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

When the **POD** (probably you was mentioning the pod, not the container) will be deleted, nothing will happen because the Deployment will re-deploy another pod to meet the replicas requirement.

When the **Deployment** will be deleted the PVC will remain as well as your data will remain in your filesystem.

To remove the **PVC**, you need to specifically delete the it:

```
kubectl delete pvc pvc-name
```

but your data persist into the filesystem after the PVC deletion.

Please, refer to [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) for more information.